# identify non pandas datetimeindex?

Tags: python, pandas

How to identify and delete non `datetimeindex` rows in following index.

`Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, u'aveValue', u'minValue', u'maxValue', u'firstValue', u'lastValue', u'nPointsTot', u'nGood', u'nBlankTimes', u'nBlankValues', u'level_nGood', u'level_nSuspect', u'level_nBad', u'status_nGood',  u'2009-01-01 00:00:00', u'2009-01-01 00:05:00', u'2009-01-01 00:10:00', u'2009-01-01 00:15:00', u'2009-01-01 00:20:00', u'2009-01-01 00:25:00', u'2009-01-01 00:30:00', u'2009-01-01 00:35:00', u'2009-01-01 00:40:00', u'2009-01-01 00:45:00', u'2009-01-01 00:50:00', u'2009-01-01 00:55:00', u'2009-01-01 01:00:00', u'2009-01-01 01:05:00', u'2009-01-01 01:10:00', u'2009-01-01 01:15:00', , ...], dtype='object')`

I need to remove the rows where index is not a timestamp.
What's the most efficient way to do this?

```
#type (df[0].index)
=> class 'pandas.core.index.Index'
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [SO]! Please check your formatting in order to make your question readable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the index [to datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), coerce errors, and filter `NaT` results:

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce').to_series().notnull().values]
```

In order to use the `notnull` method, I convert the datetime index to a series. I then convert the series to a boolean vector that can be used for indexing.

**Edit**

This should work for any pandas version:

```
df[pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')).notnull().values]
```

Comment: got following error when i use this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'notnull'

Comment: Can you try `df[pd.notnull(df.index.to_datetime(errors='coerce'))]` instead?

Comment: TypeError: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'

Comment: "df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce') " this only works for datetime. when i use notnull or dropna then i got errors. help me to delete string in index.

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_series'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: pandas version 0.16.0